# Postgres "invalid input syntax for type oid:"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am using Postgres 10 on Centos (PostgreSQL 10.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit)

When I execute the SQL statement below I receive the error "invalid input syntax for type oid:"

```
SELECT persistenceid, process_id, process_id AS case_id, completed_date_time,
       created_date_time::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS created_date_time,
       status, customer_id, request_type AS ticket_type, user_id, requestor_id,
       requester, customer_id, jira_ticket, feedback_type, priority,
       public_request, request_method, title,
       convert_from(lo_get(description::oid),'UTF8') AS description
FROM supportrequest
WHERE (user_id=5 OR requestor_id=5)
  AND customer_id='346361'
ORDER BY created_date_time DESC;
```

If I execute the statement without the WHERE clause It works fine.

Comment: What is the type and content of the "description" column, which you're carrying to oid in the select list?

Comment: It is a varchar... set by the application. We are just pulling stats from the table so I don't have control to change the type the way I would like to. I don't see any non-numerical characters that might cause it and logs are not printing any additional details

Comment: @norris-md - it can be empty string - `select ''::oid;`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If I execute

```
SELECT persistenceid, process_id, process_id AS case_id, completed_date_time,
       created_date_time::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS created_date_time,
       status, customer_id, request_type AS ticket_type, user_id, requestor_id,
       requester, customer_id, jira_ticket, feedback_type, priority,
       public_request, request_method, title,
       CASE
            WHEN TRUE = description ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' THEN convert_from(lo_get(description::oid),'UTF8')
            WHEN FALSE = description ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' THEN description::varchar
           ELSE null END
       AS description
FROM supportrequest
WHERE (user_id=5 OR requestor_id=5)
AND (customer_id='346361')
ORDER BY created_date_time DESC;
```

it revealed a carriage return as the first character in a now of the field columns for description.

Comment: the `CASE` looks little bit obscure. You can write just `CASE WHEN description ~ '...' THEN ... ELSE ... END`. The `ELSE null` is nonsense.

Comment: Agree just did a quit job